# Regex to match all capital and underscore

Tags: regex

I need a Regex to test a string whether match the follow rules:

1. Contains at least a word (could be only a character)
2. All characters should be capital.
3. Use one, and only one, underscore (`_`) between each word pairs (e.g. `HELLO_WOLRD`)

The test values (valid and invalid):

```
const validConstants = [
  'A',
  'HELLO',
  'HELLO_WORLD',
];
const invalidConstants = [
  '',               // No empty string
  'Hello',          // All be Capitals
  'Add1',           // No numbers
  'HelloWorld',     // No camel cases
  'HELLO_WORLD_',   // Underscores should only be used between words
  '_HELLO_WORLD',   // Underscores should only be used between words
  'HELLO__WORLD',   // Too much Underscores between words
];
```

I tried `^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)+$`, but it fails in `A` and `HELLO`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a `*` quantifier at the end:

```
^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*$
                  ^
```

The `(?:_[A-Z]+)*` will match *zero* or more sequences of `_` and 1 or more uppercase ASCII letters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9jESAH/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[A-Z]+` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters (the `+` here requires at least one letter in the string)
- `(?:_[A-Z]+)*` - a non-capturing group matching zero or more sequences of:

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[A-Z]+` -  1+ uppercase ASCII letters (the `+` here means the string cannot end with `_`)
- `$` - end of string anchor