# Replacement for isAlpha() to include underscores?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am processing data using Python3 and I need to read a results file that looks like this:

```
ENERGY_BOUNDS 
  1.964033E+07  1.733253E+07  1.491825E+07  1.384031E+07  1.161834E+07  1.000000E+07  8.187308E+06  6.703200E+06
  6.065307E+06  5.488116E+06  4.493290E+06  3.678794E+06  3.011942E+06  2.465970E+06  2.231302E+06  2.018965E+06
GAMMA_INTERFACE
     0
EIGENVALUE 
  1.219034E+00
```

I want to search the file for a specific identifier (in this case ENERGY_BOUNDS), begin reading the numeric values after this identifier but not the identifier itself, and stop when I reach the next identifier. However, my problem is that I was using isAlpha to find the next identifier, and some of them contain underscores. Here is my code:

```
def read_data_from_file(file_name, identifier):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        list_of_results = []
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            # For each line, check if line contains the string
            if identifier in line:
            # If yes, read the next line
                nextValue = next(read_obj)
                while(not nextValue.strip().isalpha()): # Keep on reading until next identifier appears 
                    list_of_results.extend(nextValue.split())
                    nextValue = next(read_obj)
    return(list_of_results)
```

I think I need to use regex, but I am stuck regarding how to phrase it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you dont necessarily need regex, are you just trying to retrieve the values under the identifier you specify?

Comment: If you want identifiers, then why are you using `isalpha` instead of `isidentifier`?

Comment: My file has maybe 50 different identifiers in in, and I want to be able to define this function and then reuse it for each of them. The end identifier may also change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*$`

Additionally, you can modify the regex to match strings of custom length, like this: `^[A-Z]{2,10}+(?:_[A-Z]+)*$`, where `{2, 10}` is `{MIN, MAX}` length:

[image]

You can find this demo here: https://regex101.com/r/9jESAH/35

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43224859/5461570) for more details.

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_ I know regex101 gives an explanation, but you should still include the gist here so that your answer isn't broken in case regex101 disappears in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
take = False

with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for line in input:
        if line.strip() == "ENERGY_BOUNDS":
            take = True
            continue  # we don't actually want this line
        if all(char.isalpha() or char=="_" for char in line.strip()):  # we've hit the next section
            take = False
        if take:
            print(line)  # or whatever else you want to do with this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option for you.

Just iterate over the file until you hit the identifier.
Then iterate over it in another `for` loop until the next identifier causes a `ValueError`.

```
def read_data_from_file(file_name, identifier):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        list_of_results = []
        for line in f:
            if identifier in line:
                break

        for line in f:
            try:
                list_of_results.extend(map(float, line.split()))
            except ValueError:
                break
    return list_of_results
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to verify a string has alpha, uppercase and lowercase and underscore:

```
RE_PY_VAR_NAME="^[a-zA-Z_]+$"
def isAlphaUscore(s:str) -> bool:
    assert not s is None, "s cannot be None"
    return re.search(RE_PY_VAR_NAME, s)
```